# How to do hide and show my div through checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**In following code I don't know how many rows is here which is dynamic. first of all we have to all div hidden. When i checked(//first input) after checked checkbox only it's div should be visible.**

```
<?php 
    $checkboxid=0;
    foreach($products as $product){ 
        $checkboxid = $checkboxid+1;
?>
    <tr>
       <td class="text-center">
          //first input<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $product['id'];?>" id="<?php echo $checkboxid; ?>"><br/>              
          <div class="<?php echo $checkboxid; ?>">
              <input name="chile" type="checkbox" value="" ><br/>
              <input name="miami" type="checkbox" value="" >
          </div>
       </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: use jquery show() and hide()

Comment: check the checkbox id if checked then show else hide or vice versa as per your requirment

Comment: Please read question carefully, I don't know there How many rows so we can not use any static id or class.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use class for easy implementation like so :

```
<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $product['id'];?>" id="<?php echo $checkboxid; ?>" class="myCheckBox">
```

Then attach change handler onto `myCheckBox` class like below :

```
$(document).on('change', '.myCheckBox', function () {
  // or .next().next() change to .nextAll('div')
  // in case only one of div element are existed
  if ( this.checked ) $(this).next().next().show();
  else  $(this).next().next().hide();
});
```

For better approach put class inside respective div like so :

```
<div class="<?php echo $checkboxid; ?> myDiv">
    <input name="chile" type="checkbox" value="" ><br/>
    <input name="miami" type="checkbox" value="" >
</div>
```

Then in js code just filtered next input with matched selector only :

```
$(document).on('change', '.myCheckBox', function () {      
  if ( this.checked ) $(this).nextAll('.myDiv').show();
  else  $(this).nextAll('.myDiv').hide();
});
```

**Updated**

> I don't know there How many rows so we can not use any static id or class

In this case, `class` is suitable for you

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/eg3rchx7/)

Comment: HI Ghazali, Please read question carefully, I don't know there How many rows so we can not use any static id or class.

Comment: Why mate, class are for multiple element, even sharing the same name but we differentiate it with $(this) which is stand for current clicked checkbox. See the demo attached, all table rows having same structure. I'm not giving example using static id, but using class cause when playing with dynamically content, class more suite for this.

Comment: If you're not so unsure, check the updated demo again. I make table rows dynamically(like we dont know how many of them are existed)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#checkbox1').change(function () {
    if (!this.checked) 
       $('#autoUpdate').fadeIn('slow');
    else 
        $('#autoUpdate').fadeOut('slow');
});
});
```

you can do like this

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/3WEVr/)***

Comment: HI Arijit, Please read question carefully, I don't know there How many rows so we can not use any static id or class.

Comment: I don't think so, when you are using foreach loop ensure, you assign them id or atleast a class